# How to sort appfilter.xml by name=""?

Tags: android, xml, sorting

I'm trying to make appfilter.xml in my Android project to be sorted alphabetically by the name. I've tried sorting it with VS Code command but it just sorted by the each letter that is next in component.

I want this:

```
  <item component="ComponentInfo{adriandp.ninedash/adriandp.view.main.view.MainActivity}" drawable="nine_dash" name="Nine Dash"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{ai.asleep.android_aaron/ai.asleep.android_aaron.presentation.splash.SplashActivity}" drawable="generic_moon" name="Sleep Tracker"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.shirogames.evoland12/air.com.shirogames.evoland12.AIRAppEntry}" drawable="evoland" name="Evoland"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.unit9.bkFrApp/air.com.unit9.bkFrApp.AppEntry}" drawable="burger_king" name="Burger King"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.unit9.bkFrApp/air.com.unit9.bkFrApp.MainActivity}" drawable="burger_king" name="Burger King"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{alarm.clock.calendar.reminder.pro/home.Activity_List}" drawable="reminder_pro" name="Reminder Pro"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{alarm.clock.calendar.reminder/home.Activity_List}" drawable="reminder_pro" name="Reminder"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{allterco.bg.shelly/allterco.bg.shelly.activities.MainActivity}" drawable="shelly" name="Shelly"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{androidx.compose.material.catalog/androidx.compose.material.catalog.CatalogActivity}" drawable="material_catalog" name="Compose Material Catalog"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{ani.saikou.beta/ani.saikou.MainActivity}" drawable="saikou" name="Saikou β"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.accrescent.client/app.accrescent.client.ui.MainActivity}" drawable="generic_moon" name="Accrescent"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.attestation.auditor/app.attestation.auditor.AttestationActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_auditor" name="Auditor"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.fedilab.nitterizeme/app.fedilab.nitterizeme.activities.MainActivity}" drawable="trust_wallet" name="Trust Wallet"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.fedilab.nitterizeme/app.fedilab.nitterizeme.MainActivity}" drawable="trust_wallet" name="Trust Wallet"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.grapheneos.apps/app.grapheneos.apps.ui.MainActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_apps" name="GrapheneOS Apps"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.grapheneos.apps/org.grapheneos.apps.client.ui.container.MainActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_apps" name="Apps"/>
```

To change be sorted like this:

```
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.accrescent.client/app.accrescent.client.ui.MainActivity}" drawable="generic_moon" name="Accrescent"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.grapheneos.apps/org.grapheneos.apps.client.ui.container.MainActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_apps" name="Apps"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.attestation.auditor/app.attestation.auditor.AttestationActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_auditor" name="Auditor"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.unit9.bkFrApp/air.com.unit9.bkFrApp.AppEntry}" drawable="burger_king" name="Burger King"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.unit9.bkFrApp/air.com.unit9.bkFrApp.MainActivity}" drawable="burger_king" name="Burger King"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{androidx.compose.material.catalog/androidx.compose.material.catalog.CatalogActivity}" drawable="material_catalog" name="Compose Material Catalog"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.shirogames.evoland12/air.com.shirogames.evoland12.AIRAppEntry}" drawable="evoland" name="Evoland"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.grapheneos.apps/app.grapheneos.apps.ui.MainActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_apps" name="GrapheneOS Apps"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{adriandp.ninedash/adriandp.view.main.view.MainActivity}" drawable="nine_dash" name="Nine Dash"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{alarm.clock.calendar.reminder.pro/home.Activity_List}" drawable="reminder_pro" name="Reminder Pro"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{alarm.clock.calendar.reminder/home.Activity_List}" drawable="reminder_pro" name="Reminder"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{ani.saikou.beta/ani.saikou.MainActivity}" drawable="saikou" name="Saikou β"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{allterco.bg.shelly/allterco.bg.shelly.activities.MainActivity}" drawable="shelly" name="Shelly"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{ai.asleep.android_aaron/ai.asleep.android_aaron.presentation.splash.SplashActivity}" drawable="generic_moon" name="Sleep Tracker"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.fedilab.nitterizeme/app.fedilab.nitterizeme.activities.MainActivity}" drawable="trust_wallet" name="Trust Wallet"/>
  <item component="ComponentInfo{app.fedilab.nitterizeme/app.fedilab.nitterizeme.MainActivity}" drawable="trust_wallet" name="Trust Wallet"/>
```

Comment: Other than VS Code -> sort, what have you searched for and what have you tried?

Comment: @j_b tried seeing if android studio has anything but didn't find anything. I've been trying look for something but nothing seems to be what I need.

Answer (score 0):

One option that might work for you would be to extract the 'name="...."' portions of the xml tags and then paste those to the front of their respective lines and then sort that output.  You can then remove the pasted portion and have sorted output:

```
paste <(grep -o 'name=\".*\"' src.txt) src.txt | sort | cut -f 2-
```

Output:

```
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.accrescent.client/app.accrescent.client.ui.MainActivity}" drawable="generic_moon" name="Accrescent"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.grapheneos.apps/org.grapheneos.apps.client.ui.container.MainActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_apps" name="Apps"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.attestation.auditor/app.attestation.auditor.AttestationActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_auditor" name="Auditor"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.unit9.bkFrApp/air.com.unit9.bkFrApp.AppEntry}" drawable="burger_king" name="Burger King"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.unit9.bkFrApp/air.com.unit9.bkFrApp.MainActivity}" drawable="burger_king" name="Burger King"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{androidx.compose.material.catalog/androidx.compose.material.catalog.CatalogActivity}" drawable="material_catalog" name="Compose Material Catalog"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.shirogames.evoland12/air.com.shirogames.evoland12.AIRAppEntry}" drawable="evoland" name="Evoland"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.grapheneos.apps/app.grapheneos.apps.ui.MainActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_apps" name="GrapheneOS Apps"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{adriandp.ninedash/adriandp.view.main.view.MainActivity}" drawable="nine_dash" name="Nine Dash"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{alarm.clock.calendar.reminder.pro/home.Activity_List}" drawable="reminder_pro" name="Reminder Pro"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{alarm.clock.calendar.reminder/home.Activity_List}" drawable="reminder_pro" name="Reminder"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{ani.saikou.beta/ani.saikou.MainActivity}" drawable="saikou" name="Saikou β"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{allterco.bg.shelly/allterco.bg.shelly.activities.MainActivity}" drawable="shelly" name="Shelly"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{ai.asleep.android_aaron/ai.asleep.android_aaron.presentation.splash.SplashActivity}" drawable="generic_moon" name="Sleep Tracker"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.fedilab.nitterizeme/app.fedilab.nitterizeme.MainActivity}" drawable="trust_wallet" name="Trust Wallet"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.fedilab.nitterizeme/app.fedilab.nitterizeme.activities.MainActivity}" drawable="trust_wallet" name="Trust Wallet"/>
```

Contents of src.txt:

```
<item component="ComponentInfo{adriandp.ninedash/adriandp.view.main.view.MainActivity}" drawable="nine_dash" name="Nine Dash"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{ai.asleep.android_aaron/ai.asleep.android_aaron.presentation.splash.SplashActivity}" drawable="generic_moon" name="Sleep Tracker"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.shirogames.evoland12/air.com.shirogames.evoland12.AIRAppEntry}" drawable="evoland" name="Evoland"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.unit9.bkFrApp/air.com.unit9.bkFrApp.AppEntry}" drawable="burger_king" name="Burger King"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{air.com.unit9.bkFrApp/air.com.unit9.bkFrApp.MainActivity}" drawable="burger_king" name="Burger King"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{alarm.clock.calendar.reminder.pro/home.Activity_List}" drawable="reminder_pro" name="Reminder Pro"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{alarm.clock.calendar.reminder/home.Activity_List}" drawable="reminder_pro" name="Reminder"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{allterco.bg.shelly/allterco.bg.shelly.activities.MainActivity}" drawable="shelly" name="Shelly"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{androidx.compose.material.catalog/androidx.compose.material.catalog.CatalogActivity}" drawable="material_catalog" name="Compose Material Catalog"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{ani.saikou.beta/ani.saikou.MainActivity}" drawable="saikou" name="Saikou β"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.accrescent.client/app.accrescent.client.ui.MainActivity}" drawable="generic_moon" name="Accrescent"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.attestation.auditor/app.attestation.auditor.AttestationActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_auditor" name="Auditor"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.fedilab.nitterizeme/app.fedilab.nitterizeme.activities.MainActivity}" drawable="trust_wallet" name="Trust Wallet"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.fedilab.nitterizeme/app.fedilab.nitterizeme.MainActivity}" drawable="trust_wallet" name="Trust Wallet"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.grapheneos.apps/app.grapheneos.apps.ui.MainActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_apps" name="GrapheneOS Apps"/>
<item component="ComponentInfo{app.grapheneos.apps/org.grapheneos.apps.client.ui.container.MainActivity}" drawable="grapheneos_apps" name="Apps"/>
```